# How can I use next + express in production

Tags: express, next.js

When I run "yarn start" it runs only my next application but not my express server.

I have already tried something Like "SET NODE_ENV=production && node server/server.js" but it turns on the develop version (with js not compressed).

Is there a way to use the next build version with the express server?

Comment: Are you using a [custom server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server) in Next.js, or is the Express server for backend and separate from Next.js?

Comment: Im using in Next.js, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can:

1. Next (Frontend, PORT: 3000)
2. Express (Backend, PORT: 5000)
3. Install `pm2` globally
4. To run the Next build version, navigate to the project directory then:

   - `pm2 start yarn --name "next" -- start`
5. To run the Express server, navigate to the server directory then:

   - `pm2 start server.js --name "server"`
6. Use PM2 configuration file to manage multiple applications.

Comment: HI Man thanks for the answer. I'm running the express in another Port, but in the application I'm using Axios to post somenthing to express. In the BaseUrl I use just a "/". The Quality url is something like wwwqa.test.com , how can I set this base url to ask for 5000 port?

Comment: If the two apps will be on the same machine you can still POST to `localhost:5000/`

Answer (score 0):

I just had to use

```
"start": "export NODE_ENV=production&&node server/server.js"
```

The export was missing because my OS is redhat.
Before I was trying without the export.